# Absolute position bug in safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I have problems setting absolute position here.

I want `a.jpg` attached on top of `secondimage.jpg` and all browsers work except safari. The `a.jpg` will be far left instead of next to `secondimage`

I have

```
<div id='div'>
<img class='imageClass' src='a.jpg' />
<img src='secondimage.jpg' />

<img class='imageClass' src='b.jpg' />
<img src='secondimage.jpg' />
</div>
```

css

```
div{
text-align:right;
}

.imageClass{
position:absolute;
width:20px;
height:20px;
}
```

I can't specify `top` or `left` property becasue they are all dynamic and it seems chrome and ff work without those properties...

Comment: you have an apostrophe after `absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div{text-align:right;}
.imageClass{float:left;width:20px;height:20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position: relative to div:

```
div { position: relative; text-align:right; }
```